# What is Yihan's number?

Tags: number-theory, word-problem

Problem:Haoyu gives Mingze and Yihan two different positive integers, and tells them that the product of their numbers is less than $2022.$ They are also aware that they have two different positive integers. They have the following conversation:
Mingze: I'm not sure whose number is larger.
Yihan: Me neither.
Mingze: Ah! Then my number is larger.
Yihan: Now I know your number!
What is Yihan's number?

$\textbf{(A)} ~41 \qquad \textbf{(B)} ~42 \qquad \textbf{(C)} ~43 \qquad \textbf{(D)} ~44 \qquad \textbf{(E)} ~45$

This question confuses me. Let's just say Mingze's number is $x$, while Yihan's number is $y$. I know that $xy<2022$, but then what? I don't know what to do with the conversation they had. Please enlighten me on how to solve this problem!

Comment: Please Help!!!!

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.

Comment: A reference:  A. K. Austin,"A calculus for know/don't know problems" Mathematics Magazine Vol. $49$, No. $1$, Jan., 1976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Mingze's number were at least $45,$ he would know that Yihan's number must be smaller, or else the product would be at least $45\cdot 46 > 2022.$ Thus, his number is at most $44,$ and by the same reasoning, Yihan's is as well. In fact, Yihan's number is at most $43,$ since otherwise she would know that her number was larger. The only way that Mingze can then know that his number is larger is if it is either $43$ or $44.$ If Yihan's number were $42$ or smaller, she wouldn't be able to figure out which of $43$ or $44$ was Mingze's number, so her number must be $43,$ which is $\fbox{(C)}.$

Comment: You are suspicious... Isn't that the same thing as the solution I have??